# Access files from custom 404 html page in Glassfish 3 (eg. stylesheet or images)

Tags: servlets, glassfish-3

I've created custom 404 html page for Glassfish 3.1 in case of our application is down due to redeploy or some other failures.

But my 404.html doesn't want to search stylesheet and images files relative to its path (it is placed in domain1\docroot\ ). Every resource is searched in myApp context. That's far from what i want, since while redeploy there would be nothing in that location.

I've embedded styles into html, but this can't be done with images.
Storing images on other server would be to much trouble.

Is there a way to get to the docroot folder?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've created new application (DynamicWebProject in Eclipse) that contains just the files I needed in 404.html (and of course automatically generated META-INF, WEB-INF folders as well). 
Then I've deployed it next to the primary application.
My 404.html file contains following reference to external resources:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myResourcesApp/style.css"></link>
```

Note the first slash "/" in href, which forces browser to search resource in the same domain where 404.html file is.